# Sympy convert string to function which accepts arrays

Tags: python, function, sympy

So I am trying to convert a string function expression, to an a function which can take a numpy array ideally.

So far I have this:

```
import sympy as sp
expr = "x^2 + y^2"
f = sp.sympify(expr)
symbol_list = []
for symbol in f.free_symbols:
        symbol = sp.Symbol(str(symbol))
        symbol_list.append(symbol)
```

Now the function `f` will be able to be used using `sp.subs` but I want to substitute a numpy array for `x, y`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within SymPy, `f` is called *symbolic expression*. Sympy also exposes `lambdify`, which allows to convert a symbolic expression to a numerical function.

```
# extract the symbols from the symbolic expression: order them alphabetically.
# This will be used to create the signature of the numerical function.
signature = sorted(f.free_symbols, key=str)
print(signature)
# out: [x, y]

# create the numerical function
num_f = lambdify(signature, f)

# evaluation
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1, 10)
y = 2
print(num_f(x, y))
# out: array([ 5,  8, 13, 20, 29, 40, 53, 68, 85])
```